# How can I add RDFa to my Google Site?

Tags: html, semantic-web, google-sites, schema.org, rdfa

It seems that Google encourages people to add semantics to their sites, by using either Microdata, Microformats, or RDFa [[1]](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en). Well, I tried adding RDFa tags from `schema.org` and `rdf.data-vocabulary.org` to my Google Site, as suggested by Google again [[2]](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146646), but it didn't work.

First, I added RDFa directly to my Google Site, but when I saved the changes, they were all discarded (`<span>` tags were left without any attributes). Then, I added an HTML box with a `<div hidden>` attribute and it was not discarded, but the RDFa that I added was still not recognized, according to [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets). When I tested manually my HTML code in this tool, it worked fine.

Here is a snippet of my RDFa:

```
<div hidden vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Person">
  <span property="name">My name</span>
  <span property="jobTitle">My job title</span>
  <span property="affiliation">My university</span>
  <span property="url">https://sites.google.com/site/myWebSite/</span>
</div>
```

So, my question is:
**(How) is it possible to add RDFa to Google sites?**

Comment: Could you paste a sample where you think it should work but the testing tool denies?

Comment: @ooxi I have updated my question with a sample.

Comment: Is that the markup generated by Google Site? The markup you pasted in your question works for at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004f8ed794db72fdaf65a958d01633a

Comment: @scor No, I generated this, based on the RDFa sample of http://schema.org/Person I know it works as it is (HTML code), but it doesn't work as in my website. When I put my website's url in this tool, I don't get this info. Instead, I get: 
rdfa-node
property: 
title: Vasilis Efthymiou
description: Vasilis Efthymiou's homepage

Item 
type: http://schema.org/webpage
property: 
name: Vasilis Efthymiou
description: Vasilis Efthymiou's homepage

perhaps there is something else marked up that prevents the new annotation? I don't recall having added any other RDFa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Google Sites* seems to remove some attributes (including those needed for RDFa and Microdata) when entering the markup in the HTML mode.

Workaround: <kbd>Insert</kbd> → <kbd>HTML Box</kbd>

This creates a box which seems to allow full HTML (and also CSS/JavaScript).

Comment: I have already tried that, as I state in the question with the HTML sample provided, but I still do not see this info (name, jobTitle affiliation, url) in Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

Comment: @vefthym: Ah sorry, I missed that. It works for me with HTML Box, though. -- Do you see the RDFa when inspecting the source? If yes, then your problem is not related to Google Sites but to Google’s testing tool. Did you also try it without `hidden`?

Comment: @vefthym: (I edited my comment, you might have missed it): Did you also try it without specifying `hidden`?

Comment: I just tried that and it still doesn't work. Maybe there is another error preventing my code from being validated. I will look at it and post any updates.

Comment: @vefthym: It seems that you have a `data-caja-property` attribute instead of a `property` attribute (all your RDFa attributes have a `data-caja-` prefix).

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that! How can I resolve this then? (My HTML box code is exactly the one shown in the question.)

Comment: I accept this answer, since it seems to be working for other people. I guess the problem is somewhere else in my code... Thanks!